# unknown attribute 'discussion_id' for Reply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm encountering an error "unknown attribute 'discussion_id' for Reply" 
Still learning rails and not yet good so am struggling here
My knowledge in rails is beginners level so kindly pardon me if I am asking a question which maybe trivial.

Thanks in advance.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@discussion, @discussion.replies.build], remote: true) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <div class="control">
    <%= f.input :reply, input_html: { class: 'textarea' }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class: 'label' } %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= f.button :submit, 'Leave a reply', class:'button is-info' %>

<% end %>
```

Display of replies and comment sections 
error message: Extracted source (around line #1):

[ActiveRecord::Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz80P.jpg) [Migration:AddDiscussionIdToReplies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkjBp.jpg)[Migration:AddUserIdToReplies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFmP.jpg)

Comment: Have you added a `discussion_id` column to your `replies` table? You also want to use `simple_form_for([@discussion, @reply], remote: true)` and assign `@reply = @discussion.replies.new` in the controller. If you use `@discussion.replies.build` it will always bind the form to a new instance so that anything entered will be lost if the record is not valid.

Comment: Share your schema, migration and model files for `reply` and `discussion`.

Comment: yeah i added discussion_id to replies tables

Comment: sure will share my schema, migration and model files @suresh

Answer (score 0):

**UPD: As Max mentioned in the comment below** my initial answer would not be useful for your exact question. It might help with not getting the new error further down the road but in reality, the Error that you are getting  `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` might be only related to the fact that the attribute  `discussion_id` is not present in your Reply model and your Replies table in the Database. You would want to add the `validates :discussion_id, presence: true` to your Reply model and also  run in the terminal:

`rails generate migration add_discussion_id_to_replies discussion_id:integer`

to generate the migration file and then run

`rake db:migrate`

to migrate it.

So that the `discussion_id` column is added to your Replies table in the database.

**Previous answer** 
 You need to add the `:discussion_id` to your stong params for the `reply`. To do so you need to add at the end of the  app/controllers/replies_contorller.rb  private method like so:

```
private 
def reply_params
    params.require(:reply).permit(:id, :reply, :discussion_id)
end
```

everything in the brackets after permit will reflect the attributes permitted in the params hash for your reply model. If you need more details please post the `reply` model with attributes in your question and I can help you to add the necessary. You can also read more about strong parameters here https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: In what way is this answer relevant to `unknown attribute 'discussion_id' for Reply`?

Comment: Hi Max, I am also a newbie and If the discussion_id is not in the strong prams he will get an error. I did get stuck on this error myself. Just helping him to avoid it.

Comment: Max, my bad. The ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError is only related to the fact that the attribute is not in the model and/or DB. You are right.

Comment: Have already added the migration files for replies and discussion if i do it,it will not work.

Comment: Could you clarify, please did you add the discussion_id to the migration or did you already create the initial migration? If one migration was created you can always add an additional column to the table with the next migration and run rake db:migrate again. You can also run the rake db:rollback to undo the migrations. One important thing though you do not want to alter your migration files before you run the db:rollback.  The migration files should have the same structure as your schema.rb to not mess up the database.

Comment: Could you post the exact text of the error that you are getting and, as Max mentioned at the very beginning, the Model and the migration for Reply?

Comment: Also, are you getting this error when you are running the app or when you are running the tests?

Comment: so have added some images from schema migrations hope its helps and the exact error[ ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in Discussions#show]unknown attribute 'discussion_id' for Reply.

Comment: Error pops up during testing

Comment: @Odechie-Williams I'm looking at your migration and see that you add `discussion_Id` with the capital `I` instead of `discussion_id` would you mind to run rake db:rollback to undo this migration, update the `discussion_Id` to the `discussion_id` and run `rake db:migrate again`?  Also in your  app/models/reply.rb model do you have the statement  `belongs_to :discussion` ? Let me know what you get with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot just noticed the mistake i made,will run the roll back and inform you later